# Image in chrome extension pop-up not loading

Tags: javascript, html, image, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension. In the pop-up window I need to load a few images from other websites. I do so with javascript

```
const image = document.createElement('img');
image.src = "https://whatever.com/images/icon.png";
```

At the time that I am writing one of the site seems to be down and thus when I click on the icon of my extension to display the pop-up it loads many seconds before displaying the pop-up.

What can I do to prevent my pop-up to bug in the event where one of the website is down? I mean I would prefer to load the pop-up fast and have the image not loaded.

Comment: `image.onerror = functionToCallWhenItErrors;`

Comment: Download the icon, include it with your extension, and use it directly, not remotely.

Comment: I want the icon to be up-to-date if the website decide to change it.
`image.onerror` does not fix my problem